# PHP creating/merging array by unique values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I' ve fallen into endless foreach's.

I got an array:

```
$array[0] = array( A,B );
$array[1] = array( A,C );
$array[2] = array( B,C );
$array[3] = array( B,E );
$array[4] = array( C,E );
```

What I need to get is this:

```
$array[0] = array( A,B,C );
$array[1] = array( A,B,E );
$array[2] = array( A,C,E );
$array[3] = array( B,C,E );
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this by a simple function? Also I need to create 4 value arrays of this results above: A,B,C,E etc.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more precise, what you mean? 1. The alphabet we know looks more like 'ABCD' and then for your first part AB,AC,BC,BE,CE look a bit strange to me, like you have forgotten AE...

Comment: It don't think it matter what the letters are. He just wants the cartesian product of the unique array elements.

Comment: Looks like you missed `A,E` pair in the first part. Otherwise I see no logic in the way you organize them. @webbiedave No, it is not a cartesian product. It is a permutation list.

Comment: it is not alphabet in there, treat letters as numbers A=1,B=2 and so on. I need to create patterns from first example ( 3 item ones ) and from 3 item arrays I need to create 4 item arrays.. and so on

Comment: Is this homework? There's a homework tag you need to put on there.

Comment: @kirilloid from first example you take A, B and look for arrays starting with B thats how we create A,B,C. Than in the next step we have A,B,E etc.

Comment: @webbiedave this is not homework, I am trying to figure out Apriori algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
$out = array();
foreach($array as $first) {
    foreach($array as $second) {
        if (array_slice($first, 1) == array_slice($second, -1)) {
            $copy = $first;
            $last = array_slice($second, -1, 1);
            $copy []= $last[0];
            $out []= $copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but as Kerwindena code, this would only for for creating 3 item long arrays. I already have messy code for making 2 item long arrays. Thats why I am trying to make function for that.

Comment: No, this is a general code for 2->3, 3->4, etc generation. For any step.

Comment: Oh.. sorry than I didn't get it. I will try it now.

Comment: This is almost perfect.. changed == statement on != and it gives good results but some of them are the same like A,B,C and A,C,B ( it is the same for this case ).So now I have to sort it and replace duplicated arrays. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: if you sort the input, and every input is only once present, each output will be sorted an also only once present...

Comment: this is my input     Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) )

Comment: yes, this is the result Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) so here is the duplicated one

Comment: can you change `if (array_slice($first, 1) != array_slice($second, -1)) {` to `if (array_slice($first, 1) == array_slice($second, 0, count($second)-1)) {`
I am just wondering... give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate array of unique [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), you can use code from this article:

http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/06/finding-unique-array-combinations-with-php-permutations/

Comment: Thank you for this link but what I need to make is not strictly permutations, it is joining similar arrays into wider one.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$array[0] = array( A,B );
$array[1] = array( A,C );
$array[2] = array( B,C );
$array[3] = array( B,E );
$array[4] = array( C,E );

$array2 = new array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++)
    {
        if($array[$i][1] == $array[$j][0])
        {
            $array2[] = new array($array[$i][0], $array[$i][1], $array[$j][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this would work but only for making 3 item long arrays, but than I need to match 2 first items to create 4 ones. That would require like 2 more if statements - too complicated if there were 5 item ones possible.